# Xcode 9.2 crashes exporting or importing xliff

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xliff

I can see that this is a recurring problem with all sorts of Xcode versions. I'm using the latest non-beta build (9.2 9C40b).

I have already localized in Spanish. Doing that involved *successful* exports and imports of xliff files, with same Xcode. So what changed?

I am now trying to localize to another language. This is a showstopper. Any hints? I have looked through all the posts about previous versions crashing, and have not found anything that works.

(And before you mention it, I am done and over with `genstrings`. If it exists anymore.)

Answer (score 4):

I've discovered that large *.xliff* files (more than about 6,500 lines or 1,200 `<trans-unit>` elements) cause Xcode 10.1 to crash consistently near the end of an import operation.

The work-around is to manually split the *.xliff* file into two distinct *.xliff* files, each containing a subset of the `<file>` elements in the original file. You can then import the two resulting *.xliff* files into Xcode separately without crashing.

Comment: weird, this works for me too. I never would have thought to split the file. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Do not translate "bundle name"**

I wanted to translate to Greek Language and every time I was importing xliff files, Xcode was crashing.

I realized that the problem was, that I was also translating "bundle name".

If you did the same mistake, open xliff file, find:

```
<trans-unit id="CFBundleName">
<source>NameOfYourApp</source>
```

and delete the line

```
<target>...</target>
```

After that everything worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround. Select your project icon in the Project Navigator. Select Info at top (as opposed to Build Settings). Under Localizations, click the + button and add your new language.

Xcode will create the new .strings files and fill them up with pre-existing translations. (If there are any.) Strangely, for me, some of the new .strings files were filled in with English, some with Spanish.

In any case, you have the new .strings files and can manually paste in the translations for the new language. If your app doesn't have too much user-facing text, this isn't onerous.

But really, with this problem going back to Xcode 4 (!) one would think it would be fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

it's a late answer I know, and I'm using Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61) already.

In my scenario, I added Chinese Hong Kong (zh-HK) language under Project > Info > Localization and exported successfully then sent to the agency for translations. After few days they sent to me Chinese translated text within. At that point, everything seems correct for me by eye. But I've tried 10 times to import file and it crashes 10 times without exception! Which makes me sick. I use to checked to see the difference between 2 document via Apple's File Merge App. I understand that agency geniuses added few missing <\target>   tags. Hmmm, that means while exporting Xcode didn't add for some translations <\target> tag. Interesting...

I removed those unnecessarily translated tags and checked everything was equal in 2 documents except translations of the words to the Chinese language.

Tried to import again. Then BOOM! It works like a charm! I was surprised by this. It's so weird that Xcode never shows me a descriptive message about my mistake. Probably, It's just a parse error for Xcode.

Whatever, I hope this will work for someone else.

Best.